# How to change "mediasoup" port

Tags: node.js

I installed [mediasoup](https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup-demo) and ran it as well!

But it's working on `3000` port.

I couldn't find listen port in its sources, How i can change this port to`443`?

Comment: mediasoup does NOT run on port 3000 because mediasoup is NOT an HTTP or WebSocket server. So you probably installed the mediasoup-demo instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you did not install `mediasoup` but the `mediasoup-demo` which, indeed, includes a WebSocket based signaling protocol that listens in port 3000.

`mediasoup-demo` it's just a demo, not an application or product.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to listen bellow than 1024 port then you need to run as administrator on windows and as a root(`sudo`) user on Linux/MAC that is `sudo node server.js`

and as documentation of https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup-demo, you must update port on `config.js`

```
protoo :
    {
        listenIp   : '0.0.0.0',
        listenPort : 443
    },
```